# Comparing 2 files using awk and print if matches

Tags: awk

I have two files and I want to compare the column 1 of File1 and column 10 of File2 and should print if it matches. I used this command but it only prints the last line of File2.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}NR==FNR{a[$10]=$0;next}$1 in a {print a[$1],$0}' File2 File1
```

File1:

```
003502|COMMUNICATE|Chat|MEGAMOBILE
003502|COMMUNICATE|News - Headlines|MEGAMOBILE
003502|Entertainment|Promos|MEGAMOBILE
003502|ENTERTAINMENT|Promos|MEGAMOBILE
003502|INFORMATION||MEGAMOBILE
```

File2:

```
1000012640|Libre Aquarius||||By Time||Libre Aquarius subs|1000012640|003502|0|1
1000012587|HULA Aries||||By Time||HULA Aries subs|1000012587|003502|0|1
```

Desired Output:

```
1000012587|HULA Aries||||By Time||HULA Aries subs|1000012587|003502|0|1|003502|COMMUNICATE|Chat|MEGAMOBILE
1000012587|HULA Aries||||By Time||HULA Aries subs|1000012587|003502|0|1|003502|COMMUNICATE|News - Headlines|MEGAMOBILE
1000012587|HULA Aries||||By Time||HULA Aries subs|1000012587|003502|0|1|003502|Entertainment|Promos|MEGAMOBILE
1000012587|HULA Aries||||By Time||HULA Aries subs|1000012587|003502|0|1|003502|ENTERTAINMENT|Promos|MEGAMOBILE
1000012587|HULA Aries||||By Time||HULA Aries subs|1000012587|003502|0|1|003502|INFORMATION||MEGAMOBILE
1000012640|Libre Aquarius||||By Time||Libre Aquarius subs|1000012640|003502|0|1|003502|COMMUNICATE|Chat|MEGAMOBILE
1000012640|Libre Aquarius||||By Time||Libre Aquarius subs|1000012640|003502|0|1|003502|COMMUNICATE|News - Headlines|MEGAMOBILE
1000012640|Libre Aquarius||||By Time||Libre Aquarius subs|1000012640|003502|0|1|003502|Entertainment|Promos|MEGAMOBILE
1000012640|Libre Aquarius||||By Time||Libre Aquarius subs|1000012640|003502|0|1|003502|ENTERTAINMENT|Promos|MEGAMOBILE
1000012640|Libre Aquarius||||By Time||Libre Aquarius subs|1000012640|003502|0|1|003502|INFORMATION||MEGAMOBILE
```

Comment: File 2 contains multiple entries with the same key. `$10` appears twice in the list, so in your assignment `a[$10]=$0` you overwrite the first line with the last line because the `key` (`$10`) is the same.

Comment: Your 2 files only share 1 value in the key fields. If your real input has more than that then edit your example to show more than that. If your real key values aren't sorted then make sure that's represented in your example. If there are keys that don't match between the files then show those too.

Answer (score 3):

There is a special bash command to do this job : [join][1]

I suggest you to use it instead of awk as it would be more memory efficient.

As @EdMorton said:

> join requires both input files to be sorted on the join field

```
join -t"|" -1 10 -2 1 <(sort -t"|" -k10 -n file2) <(sort -t"|" -k1 -n file1)
```

Gives

```
003502|1000012587|HULA Aries||||By Time||HULA Aries subs|1000012587|0|1|COMMUNICATE|Chat|MEGAMOBILE
003502|1000012587|HULA Aries||||By Time||HULA Aries subs|1000012587|0|1|COMMUNICATE|News - Headlines|MEGAMOBILE
003502|1000012587|HULA Aries||||By Time||HULA Aries subs|1000012587|0|1|ENTERTAINMENT|Promos|MEGAMO
003502|1000012587|HULA Aries||||By Time||HULA Aries subs|1000012587|0|1|Entertainment|Promos|MEGAMOBILE
003502|1000012640|Libre Aquarius||||By Time||Libre Aquarius subs|1000012640|0|1|COMMUNICATE|Chat|MEGAMOBILE
003502|1000012640|Libre Aquarius||||By Time||Libre Aquarius subs|1000012640|0|1|COMMUNICATE|News - Headlines|MEGAMOBILE
003502|1000012640|Libre Aquarius||||By Time||Libre Aquarius subs|1000012640|0|1|ENTERTAINMENT|Promos|MEGAMO
003502|1000012640|Libre Aquarius||||By Time||Libre Aquarius subs|1000012640|0|1|Entertainment|Promos|MEGAMOBILE
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have duplicate keys, you should keep track of those.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}
     (NR==FNR) { c[$1]++; a[$1,c[$1]]=$0; next }
     ($10 in c) { for(i=1;i<=c[$10];++i) print $0,a[$10,i] }' file1 file2
```

In the above, the array `c` keeps track of how many times we encountered key `$1`. The entries are then stored in the array `a` indexed by `$1` and the sequence number `c[$1]`. When reading `file2` we check if the key `$10` is in the original array `c`, if so, we process all the stored values in order.

Also, because of the expected output, we had to revert the file order.